# Why is my Float Variable Holding Whole Numbers?

Tags: java, variables, floating-point, numbers, number-formatting

I've been glancing at this code for a while now, and I can't seem to figure out what the probably simple error is... In short, I have a float variable in Java that seems to only be storing the integer content (whole number) of what the value is actually supposed to be. I had this bit of code working before when I had everything crammed into one function, but after I re-factored the code to use more functions, this error occurred. Here's what I've got thus far:

### Java Code

```
public class ModifyTimeController extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        PopulateTimeIntervals(request.getWriter());
    }
    protected void PopulateTimeIntervals(PrintWriter writer) {
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        float workHours = (float)0.00;

        ...
        /* Code that queries a database for TimeIntervals */
        ...

        while(resultSet.next()) {
            // I was told that this type of conversion is
            // possible since Timestamp is an extension of Date
            Date dtStart = resultSet.getTimestamp("dtStart");
            Date dtEnd = resultSet.getTimestamp("dtEnd");

            // Accumulates the hours worked in each time interval
            workHours += CalculateWorkHours(dtStart, dtEnd);
        }
        // Should print out something like: 54.27
        writer.println(numberFormat.format(workHours).toString());
    }

    protected float CalculateWorkHours(Date dtStart, Date dtEnd) {
        // Divides the difference of the start and end times 
        // (in miliseconds) by 3600000 to convert to hours
        return (dtEnd.getTime() - dtStart.getTime()) / 3600000;
    }
}
```

It's been a long day, so I'm probably just missing something... But rather than printing out something like `54.27` hours, I'm getting a flat `54` hours. The number formatting worked just fine, before... So I don't know what's up.

Comment: you shouldnt need to intialize workHours or cast 0.00 to float.  you should also only need to set the max fraction digits. why are you using += as opposed to just =    ?  if you have multiple values then workhours should be an array the += would be concatenating the results to each other

Comment: My compiler didn't like me doing just `float workHours = 0.00`, hence the casting. I could've just used `0.00f`, but I like the `(float)` approach. I use the MinimumFractionDigits because even if it was exactly 23hrs, I still want it to show 23.00hrs. And workHours is a single value that holds the amount of hours an employee has worked. The CalculateWorkHours simply returns the amount of hours worked during one time interval returned from the database and store in the result set. So the `resultSet.next()` is actually a time interval, in a manner of speaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At `return (dtEnd.getTime() - dtStart.getTime()) / 3600000;` you're dividing by an integer, and making the answer an integer. Change it to `3600000.0` (or `3600000f`) and you should be golden.

Comment: *face-palm* Yeah... Thank you. I'll accept when it allows me to.

Comment: There have been much worse cases of said error, don't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 2):

```
dtEnd.getTime() - dtStart.getTime()) / 3600000
```

This is a division of a long and int so the result itself will be a long and then be casted to float which then only holds the computed long value. To get a float result cast one of the operands to float first or use float literal like 3600000f instead.